# Quotes and other special characters within string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am trying to write a long string in VBA with many special characters and I am stuck! On the shorter string, the double quotes worked well but on my final string, it doesn't work. I do not understand what's wrong.

```
"let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\username\company\company Market Research - Documents\System\Data Project\raw data\mapped_tradeflows.csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]), #""En-têtes promus"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]), #""Type modifié"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""En-têtes promus"",{{""origin"", type text}, {""destination"", type text}, {""year"", Int64.Type}, {""month"", Int64.Type}, {""quality"", type text}, {""freight"", type text}, {""tonnage"", Double.Type}}) in #""Type modifié"""
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Any error message?

Comment: The string you show us is OK from VBA point of view. Please put it in a variable, let us say,  `Dim x as String` ,then `x = your long string`, followed by `Debug.Print x`. Examine the returned string and according to what you need, you can see where the string construction is wrong... Or, can you show us how the real string have to look?

Comment: "*doesn't work*" is not a helpful description.  What is the behavior when you try to execute the line?  Is there an error message?  If so, what is it? Where is the context?  I don't see a sample of the CSV file you are trying to access.

Comment: Also, the syntax of your code appears to be valid for M Code.  Your problem does not appear to be with the quotation marks or the length of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotations can be hard to read as you've demonstrated. Instead use `Chr(34)` to escape them.

For example

> In this string is "another string"

Instead of

```
mystring = "In this string is ""another string"""
```

Use

```
mystring = "In this string is " & Chr(34) & "another string" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: or define a constant, eg `Constant quote = """"`.

Comment: But the OP's string is correct from VBA point of view. You can test it. It can be returned in Immediate Window. The problem should be in the construction logic, I think...